# Insert DateTime into Access

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

The problem:
I'm trying to insert a date time into an access database using the Oledb interface in C#.

Hacking solution: Generate my on insert string without using command.Properties

I can insert text into the database with no problem, but when trying datetime, I end up with this error: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException {"Data type mismatch in criteria expression."}

There are several posts similar to this but alas with no working solution.

Here is my code:

```
void TransferData()
{
    string instCmd = Get_InsertCommand(0); // hard coded table 0 for testing

    Fill_ProductTable_ToInsert();

    con.Open();


    // It would be nice not to have to separate the date indexes
    int[] textIndex = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7 };
    int[] dateIndex = { 5, 6 };
    try
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in DataToStore.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = con;

            command.CommandText = instCmd;

            foreach(int j in textIndex)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + j, row[j]);
            foreach (int j in dateIndex)
            {

                // TESTING CODE
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                string input = "#\'" +DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") +"\'#";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + j,    input.ToString());
                Program.WriteLine(input.ToString());

                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            }


            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}

string Get_InsertCommand(int i)
{
    string sqlIns = "INSERT INTO " + DataToStore.Tables[0].TableName + " (";
    string temp = "VALUES (";
    for (int j = 0; j < expected_header[i].Length - 1; j++)
    {
        sqlIns += expected_header[i][j] + ", ";
        temp += "@" + j + ", ";
    }

    int lastIndex = expected_header[i].Length -1;
    sqlIns += expected_header[i][lastIndex] + ") ";
    temp += "@" + lastIndex + ")";
    sqlIns += temp;

    return sqlIns;
}
```

Inside the area labeled testing code, I have tried every permutation of date time I could think of.
I tried every format with # and '
I tried these formats: yyyy-MM-dd, yyyyMMdd, yyyy\MM\dd, yyyy/MM/dd
I also tried ToOADate()
And ToString(), ToShortDateString()

I also tried setting the database to accept ANSI-92 Sql

I'm running out of ideas.

Note: This code is set up to deal with multiple tables from multiple databases, mind the loops...

Answer (score 4):

Use parameters properly, and don't worry about the format of the datetime value that you concatenate in your query.
I don't understand why you want to convert the datetime value to a string value ?

```
DateTime theDate = new DateTime(2012,10,16);
var cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO sometable (column) VALUES (@p_bar)";
cmd.Parameters.Add ("@p_bar", OleDbType.DateTime).Value = theDate;
```

Comment: Same error, using OleDbType.Date and OleDbType.DBDate with many variations of the datetime input, Including DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.Date, new DateTime(2012,2,3), all to the same end.

Comment: print the sql statement that you've generated to the console before executing, and verify if it is correct

Comment: How do I print the full command from an OleDbCommand object?
the command format is correct, it works for string values, and If I switch the field in the database to string, I can place the date into the field, but I want to put the date in as an actual date.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by not using command properties. I generated my own sql input and set it to cmd.commandText. The text input for datetime to a data base is #yyyy-MM-dd#

Comment: It would take #dd-MM-yy# as well. #dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss# and #hh:mm:ss dd-MM-yy# too.