# Error sending data to the Access Database

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

I have this exception when I try to send my code to the Access Database:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E07): data type mismatch in a selection condition expression
>
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
> at KPIZ.Form2.btn_save_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\booku\source\repos\KPIZ\KPIZ\Form2.cs:line 110

My code:

```cs
private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] imageBt = null;
        FileStream fstream = new FileStream(this.textBox2.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
        imageBt = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);

        connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [SportInfo]([ID],[FirstName],[LastName],[DOB],[Sport],[DIW],[Image])" + "VALUES(@id, @Fn, @Ln, @Date, @Sports, @days ,@IMG)";
        
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Fn", Convert.ToString(txt_fname.Text)));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Ln", Convert.ToString(txt_lname.Text)));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Date", Convert.ToString(mtxt_dob.Text)));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Sports", Convert.ToString(txt_sport.Text)));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@days", Convert.ToInt32(nmc_diw.Text)));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@id", Convert.ToInt32(txt_id.Text)));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@IMG", imageBt));

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unlucky  " + ex);
        connection.Close();
    }

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        string query = "select ID,LastName,FirstName,DOB,Sport,DIW, from SportInfo ";
        command.CommandText = query;

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting error in insert command or select command?

Comment: insert command as i understand, it doesnt give me the "Saved" MessageBox

Comment: What is the type for Date in your database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert DateTime into Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922292/insert-datetime-into-access)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OLEDB parameters are always positional. This means the order of parameters in your query needs to match the order of parameters as they're added in your code.

Also, you need to add your date parameter to be a date, not a string.

Adjust your parameter ordering to match:

```
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@id", Convert.ToInt32(txt_id.Text)));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Fn", Convert.ToString(txt_fname.Text)));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Ln", Convert.ToString(txt_lname.Text)));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Date", DateTime.Parse(mtxt_dob.Text)));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Sports", Convert.ToString(txt_sport.Text)));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@days", Convert.ToInt32(nmc_diw.Text)));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@IMG", imageBt));
```

If the order doesn't match, you get lots of errors, because now you're trying to insert a text field in your date column or integer column.